# KOMA-Script scrbook: How to put page numbers at top-right for all \mainmatter & \backmatter

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script

Per my university's instructions for dissertations, I need the following:

1. All \frontmatter pages numbered bottom-center (Easy...I got that)
2. All other pages with numbering placed "even with the top right margin" (I'm quoting the university's literature there)

In my understanding of KOMA-script's treatment of headers/footers so far, its easiest to define requirement #2 as:  Right justified, at the bottom of the vertical space defined by the top margin.

What I'm reading in the manual about the `\pagestyle` command, and elsewhere about a `fancyhdr` package.  It's probably a simple thing, but I'm missing it somehow.  Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrpage2` was indeed what I needed (had not plowed that far into the manual before).  I'm going to include what I've gotten to work here as the answer, though I'm sure others could point out more correct ways of doing this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside,chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%Margins
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.5in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrpage2}  %<---
\pagestyle{scrheadings}%<---

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Abstract Title Page}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\chapter*{Copright Page}
\chapter*{Title Page}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\clearscrheadfoot            %<---
\rohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}%<---

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\appendix
\backmatter

\end{document}
```